# Discern albums and images via iter_messages

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I iterate throw messages via:

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(source_name, offset_date=offset_date, reverse=True):
```

But it doesn't matter if I got album or some images separately. Anyways, it will be different messages. I need to discern albums and images. How to do this?

Comment: Worth nothing that albums *are* separate messages. They just share a common identifier, like @Hack5 answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If message.grouped_id is present, it is a unique number the same for all photos within a single album. If its None, the message is not in an album.